# java syncrhonized static methods

Tags: java, static, synchronization

If I have a method like this

```
public synchronized static foo()
{

}
```

this compiles fine.

So this leads me to two questions

1. What is is syncrhonizing on?  The Class, or something else?
2. Can you synchronize on a class, does that lock all object of that class as well.

for instance could you do this

```
synchronized(Foo) // where Foo is a class
{
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is synchronizing on the `Class` object. I'm not sure if I understand your second question correctly, could you please restate it?

Comment: 1) It is synchronizing on the `Class` object. 2) It should really be `synchronized(Foo.class)`

Comment: So it is synchronizing on Foo.getClass() essentially or the class Class object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synchronized static method in `MyClass` is essentially the same as `synchronized(MyClass.class)` block. Your second example should be rewritten as

```
synchronized(Foo.class) {
}
```

to be correct.

If you would like to be defensive about your class synchronization, you should synchronize on a private static object not visible outside your class. This prevents malicious code from blocking your static methods by executing `synchronized` on their class object, thus blocking the legitimate method.

As far as "locking all objects" goes, non-static methods marked `synchronized` will not be locked by execution of a static `synchronized` method, because regular `synchronized` methods lock on an *instance* of the object, not on its class.

Comment: are they syntactically that same, will it cause a compiler error if I don't use Foo.class, does the compiler know what I mean?

Comment: @rubixibuc The compiler expects an expression that evaluates to an object to be supplied inside the parentheses of the `synchronized` block; since `Foo` is not an expression that evaluates to an object, you should get a compile error.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is synchronizing on the `Class` object. You can synchronize on any `Class` object. You can either use its literal (`Foo.class`), or use the `getClass()` method of an instance of `Foo`.

For more information about synchronized (the second page in that trail contains the information about which lock synchronized methods use): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Comment: Doe Foo by itself implicitly refer to the class object always?

Comment: @rubixibuc No, it does not, it refers to the *type* `Foo`, not the `Class`.

Comment: Does is refer in the case of a syncrhonization block?

Comment: @rubixibuc The `synchronized` block takes an object as its argument. `Foo` is not an object, but `Foo.class` is.

Answer (score 2):

1. It is synchronizing on the `class` object, eg `MyClass.class`
2. No, it doesn't lock objects of the class

Answer (score 0):

Static methods use the class as the object for locking.

The relevant section on the Java Language Specification is [8.4.3.6, 'synchronized Methods'](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#260369):

> A synchronized method acquires a monitor (§17.1) before it executes. For a class (static) method, the monitor associated with the Class object for the method's class is used. For an instance method, the monitor associated with this (the object for which the method was invoked) is used.